# sending json to another URL

Tags: java, json, web-services, url, servlets

I trying to send some json values from my servlet class to another application that is running in different system. here is my servlet class

```
   @WebServlet("/bootHttp")
public class BootServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

        String boot_request = request.getParameter("request_boot");
        System.out.println("boot_request = " + boot_request);
        // String start_request = request.getParameter("request_start");
        String json=" **{\n" +
          "\"cmschangeavailability\":\n" +
          "{\n" +
          " \"cmschangeavailabilitycpid\":\"1\",\n" +
          " \"cmschangeavailabilityconnectorid\":\"1\",\n" +
          " \"cmschangeavailabilitytype\":\"InOperative\"\n" +
          "}\n" +
          "}";**   

    }
}
```

I want to send the above json String(I can also construct json using JSONObject if requires)  to "www.devsitexxx.xom/abcd/changeavailability" URL there I can use REST webservices to do operations like below

```
@PUT
@Path("changeavailability")
@Produces({"application/json"})
@Consumes("application/json")
public jsonFormat cmsChangeAvailability(MainCMSChangeAvailabilityPOJO 
cmsChangeAvailability) throws JSONException, IOException {
}
```

Comment: Could not understand your question. can you please elaborate more? Also may I now why do you use doPut()? You could use doPost()

Comment: what I am doing is I get some values from html form and constructing it as json and sending the json to some other application that is running  as server, here with json i do business logic. Put or post that is not a problem i can change

Comment: if your problem is related to REST client, then I would suggest you to take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/ I am still not clear about your question